# Не меняется внешний вид JTabbedPane

Tags: java, swing

Столкнулся со странной проблемой, вот ее суть: я применяю Look and Feel JTattoo к своему приложению. Внешний вид таких компонентов как JRadioButton, JButton, JMenuBar успешно меняется.
Это можно видеть на скрине:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А вот вкладки JTabbedPane как были некрасивыми так и остались. Почему то JTattoo не оказал на JTabbedPane никакого влияния.
Look And Feel подключаю так:

```
javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        try {
            UIManager.setLookAndFeel("com.jtattoo.plaf.luna.LunaLookAndFeel");
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        createAndShowGui();
    }
});
```

Объясните пожалуйста, почему так происходит и как это исправить?

Comment: Проблему удалось решить.
Решение описано здесь:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33688123/jgoodies-had-no-impact-on-jtabbedpane/33699648#33699648